# Shellsorting an array from an input file

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, io, shellsort

The full project is to take data in from a file which is a text file containing a list of all 201 countries and their respective rates of internet use in alphabetical order. Here is an example

```
Afghanistan                 7
Albania                    63
Algeria                    20
Andorra                    97
Angola                     23
...
```

With this we have to Shellsort (specifically) the data numerically. I have successfully done this but I only am outputting a list of the percentages, where as I need the countries listed as well. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class InternetUsers {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String populationString = "";
    String[] line = new String[201];
    int populations[] = new int[201];   

    Scanner fileIN = new Scanner(new File("F:/CountrySortedAlpha.txt"));

    while(fileIN.hasNext()){
        for(int i = 0; i < 201; i++){
            populationString = fileIN.nextLine().substring(26, 29);
            populations[i] = Integer.parseInt(populationString.trim());
        }   
        int j;
            for(int gap = populations.length / 2; gap > 0; gap /= 2){
                for (int k = 0; k < populations.length; k++){   
                }
                for (int t = gap; t < populations.length; t++){
                    int tmp = populations[t];
                        for(j = t; j >= gap && (tmp < populations[j - gap]); j -= gap){
                            populations[j] = populations[j - gap];
                        }
                        populations[j] = tmp;
                }
        }
        System.out.println("\nFinal sorted order: ");
        for(int k = 0; k < populations.length; k++){
            System.out.print(populations[k]);
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }   
}
}
```

So my question is how am I to go about outputting the countries as well? do I need to completely redo the way I sorted? Here is my sample output:

```
 Final sorted order: 
 1
 1
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 3
 ....
```

Comment: How would you bundle country with its Internet users number?

Comment: you've declared the `line` array but you haven't used it anywhere in your code. what's the intention there?

Comment: the way the data is taken in is with the nextline function. You can fill an an array of strings with the full line for each index. But you can't compare the numbers of population percentage that way. So I parsed the string where the numbers were as a substring and trimmed blank spaces. comparisons work fine, but I need to figure out how to get the countries names to output as well

Comment: create an Object that contains both a String and an Integer.  Have an Array of these Objects, not just an integer array.  You can use two arrays (as you have `line`) but then you have to swap this array **also** when you swap the Integer array

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw the original intention was to use that to take each line from the file (which is one country and its respective internet usage percentage) and make it an index of that array. The couple ways I have tried to use it hadn't worked so whatever ways I used it originally were deleted

Comment: @NickWard I would go with what ScaryWombat has stated _create an Object that contains both a String and an Integer. Have an Array of these Objects_. Basically, the country name will be the `String` field and the corresponding number will be the `int` field, then sort the objects by their `int` fields.

Comment: @ScaryWombat my professor wants it done with the array, although that would be a good solution.

Comment: Are you certain your professor wants it done with two separate arrays: one for the names and one for the numbers? That's ... unusual, to say the least. You might ask him if an array objects is acceptable. Otherwise you have to resort to all manner of silliness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you parse the file, you need to store parsed value in a dictionary or some other structure. After you sort, when printing, read the values from dictionary.

I modified you code to store values in a dictionary, and added comments to the lines I added/modified. I did not touch your sorting algo, so you are still sorting on the same array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String populationString = "";
    String[] line = new String[201];
    int populations[] = new int[201];

    // Have a dictionary that can store the values you parse
    Map<Integer, String> dictionary = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    Scanner fileIN = new Scanner(new File("F:/CountrySortedAlpha.txt"));

    while (fileIN.hasNext()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 201; i++) {
            // Parse the whole line, this 29 hard coded seems incorrect
            populationString = fileIN.nextLine().substring(0, 29);
            // Grab both values
            String[] splited = populationString.split("\\s+");
            // Country name can have spaces, so take the last elemnt
            populations[i] = Integer.parseInt(splited[splited.length - 1]);
            // Join back values
            String country = populationString.join(" ", splited);
            // Cut off the rate number
            country = country.substring(0, country.lastIndexOf(" "));
            // Store them in your dictionary
            if (dictionary.containsKey(populations[i])) {
                // If multiple countries have same rate, add them to value, and separate with comma
                String value = dictionary.get(populations[i]);
                dictionary.put(populations[i], value + "," + country);
            } else {
                dictionary.put(populations[i], country);
            }
        }
        int j;
        for (int gap = populations.length / 2; gap > 0; gap /= 2) {
            for (int t = gap; t < populations.length; t++) {
                int tmp = populations[t];
                for (j = t; j >= gap && (tmp < populations[j - gap]); j -= gap) {
                    populations[j] = populations[j - gap];
                }
                populations[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Final sorted order: ");
        for (int k = 0; k < populations.length; k++) {
            // Read the value from dictionary
            String value = dictionary.get(populations[k]);
            // For duplicates skip, that entry gets deleted after values were printed
            if (value == null) {
                continue;
            }

            // If multiple countries had the same rate, they were stored as comma separated value
            String[] countries = value.split(",");
            for (String country : countries) {
                // You can print rate, or country, or both
                System.out.println(populations[k] + " " + country);
            }

            // Remove from dictionary, because we already printed all countries with the same rate
            dictionary.remove(populations[k]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Don't forget to close the file
    fileIN.close();
}
```

Comment: I get a number format exception at line 22 with your additions

Comment: Number format exception can occur at Integer.parseInt() call if the value is not a number. If you get that exception, then content of your file is not what you provided as a sample. This code is assuming that there is nothing after the number. Try to debug and see what is the value. I updated the code to grab the first 29 chars, which is similar to what you were doing, and that should fix your issue. These small parsing issues you should be able to overcome on your own with debugging, if you try to understand what the code is doing.

Comment: That actually worked. I'm not sure why taking the entire line isn't working. It's possible the prof wasn't careful in data entry. Now I need to hash the countries to a hashtable of size 250, with linear probing. Would you be able to help me with this as well

Comment: hash function is the ascii values of the characters right trimmed, added together, and modded by 250

Comment: That is different than your question. You need to try to solve it on your own, give your best effort, and if you can't figure it out, post a new question, and show what you have tried. Like this time : )

Answer (score 0):

Unless prof. said specifically do it with an array of Strings for the countries and an array of ints for the rates, @ScaryWombat's idea of an array of objects each containing a String and an int is the way to go.

That being said, you *could* still do it with the separate arrays if you must.  Just be sure to swap *both* the `line` **and** the `population` entries when your sort algorithm calls for a swap, not only the `population` entry.