# how can I get the index of the max value in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays

```
String[] city;
int[] temp;
```

they both have a length of 4. City holds the name of each city, and temp holds the average temperature of each city. The temps in temp are in the same order as the cities in city. So my question is, how can I get the index of the max int in temp? I want to print out

```
"The city with the highest average temperature is " + city[index] + 
" with an average temperature of " + temp[max];
```

I thought of taking the index of the max int in city, and plugging that into city[]. Since the arrays are the same size and in the same order, I just need to be able to return the index of the max value in int[] temp;

Comment: if you want to know the index of highest value, you could just walk through the array to find the largest and remember the index. or use @Alex's suggestion to use NumberUtils. side note, design issues: uh... why don't you 'bind' together the temp and city into a class..? like `city` class. then the class contains the city name and temp..?

Comment: this seems to be the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728432/shellsorting-an-array-from-an-input-file?noredirect=1#comment74500808_43728432

Comment: @ScaryWombat I cannot comment on that question as I am new, but I had a question to ask. Could you maybe expand on what you mean by creating an object that holds ints AND strings?

Comment: `public class CityTemp { String city; int temp}` `CityTemp [] = new CityTemp [201];` **this is very very rough**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want to use another class you can do the below.
You need to store both the max and the index of where max was so that you can also print the city

```
String[] city = getCities ();  // assuming this code is done
int[] temp = getTemparatures ();
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int index = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i ++){
    if(max < temp[i]){
        max = temp[i];
        index = i;
    }
}

System.out.println ("The city with the highest average temperature is " + city[index] + 
" with an average temperature of " + temp[index]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the length of an array using `<name>.length`.  The length of the array is one more than the highest index so you should use '*name*[*name*.length - 1]` to get the item with the highest index.

Comment: The question is in regards to a maximum value within the array, not the length of the array itself.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, I wrote in this editor, but the essence is the same

```
int max = -100;
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
    if (temp[i] > max){
        max = temp[i];
    }
}
System.out.print("The city with the highest average temperature is " + city[your index] + 
" with an average temperature of " + max);
```

Comment: Ok...where is the desired index value.

Comment: I hope he will come up with it himself. Not a ready decision to give...

Answer (score -3):

You could iterate through the temp array, find the max and store the value a variable, and use that variable in your output statement. Below is some code, hope this helps

```
String[] city;
int[] temp;
int max = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < temp.size; i ++){
    if(max < temp[i]){
        max = temp[i];
    }
}

"The city with the highest average temperature is " + city[max] + 
" with an average temperature of " + temp[max];
```

Comment: temp.size???? And how is this acquiring the index of the array element with the highest temperature?